# Qt5 with Qt 4.7 on Ubuntu 13.04. How to install it both without conflicts?

Tags: 13.04, qt, qt5

I'm using Qt5 and need Qt 4.7 now (for embedded device). Is it possible to install it additionally on Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I can install both libraries and when I'm making:

```
qtchooser -run-tool=qmake -qt=qt5
make
```

or

```
qmake -qt5
make
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. Look this guy reported a .[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935040/qt5-with-qt-4-7-on-ubuntu-13-04-how-to-install-without-conflicts)

There is a program called  qtchooser but it's unreliable, I could not make it work.

What I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then just remove qt5-default, it's about a few kbs of program, then you can easily switch back to qt5 installing qt5-default.

**EDIT: I found an easier way to switch between qt4** and **qt5** using environment variables

To switch to **qt4**

```
 export QTCHOOSER_RUNTOOL=qtconfig
 export QT_SELECT=4
```