# How to choose between different versions of Qt 5?

Tags: qt

I have a C++ Qt program.  It compiles using qmake && make.

It always ends up compiling using Qt 5.2.1.  I want to use Qt 5.5 that I downloaded.

```
$ qtchooser -l
4
5
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

None of those were new after I downloaded and installed Qt 5.5.

I used the Qt Creator program to 'remove' the old version of Qt such that 5.5 is the only one there now, but still it's stuck on 5.2.1 when I compile.

I want to know the official way to do this as I need to write instructions for others to compile my program.

I'm using the opensource versions of Qt.

Comment: I've now got it by linking explicitly to the qmake binary in the Qt5.5 directory, but ideally I'd like to know the "proper" command-line way to do this.

Comment: Clarification: This is what I'm doing as a workaround:

$ ~/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake && make

Comment: Qt Creator itself will use an absolute path to the required Qt version. There is nothing wrong or "unofficial" about that.

Comment: No @Anwar It's not a duplicate question.  Maybe the resolution is similar, but the question is different.  One is asking about how to make sure that a version of QT is installed properly.  The other is asking how to switch between different versions of installed QT.

Comment: @GreenMo I don't get any point in closing questions. And please don't jump into conclusion to early. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Anwar, I see, sorry for my rudeness then.  You have a nice day too :8)

Comment: I admit my target question wasn't too precise. We actually have lots of similar question. Maybe you want to make one of these as a target question. [q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326378/qt5-with-qt-4-7-on-ubuntu-13-04-how-to-install-it-both-without-conflicts), [q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820054/selecting-qt5-using-qtchooser), [q3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424161/how-to-install-both-qt5-qmake-and-qt4-qmake). They have good answers there imo

Answer (score 0):

The answer is posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921382/how-to-make-sure-that-qt5-4-2-is-installed-properly/921385#921385) , you can use the first answer and then edit `default.conf` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser` like I did here:

```
#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/debug/opt/qt54/bin
/usr/lib/debug/opt/qt54/lib
```

or you can go with the second answer. (up to you)

Comment: Posted where? There was absolutely noting in that answer about `default.conf`~

Comment: I post that question and if you read the comments there you will understand.

Comment: see  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435564/qt5-installation-and-path-configuration)

Comment: You posted the question there, so what? It's not the one that contains the source of this answer. And if the things are same, you should flag as duplicate.

Comment: it is flaged as a duplicate and when i wrote for you what i did i didn't see the answer, I have just figured that out