# How to make sure that Qt5.4.2 is installed properly

Tags: 14.04, command-line, qt

I installed qt5.4 from [here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) in Ubuntu 14.04, but when I run:

```
qmake -v
```

I always get the old version Qt5.2.1, although I think it is installed here Qt version 5.4.2 in `/opt/qt54/lib`. Can anyone tell me how to make sure that Qt5.4.2 is installed properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have both versions installed, use `whereis` command to find about all available instance of a program:

```
whereis command-name
```

e.g:

```
whereis qmake
```

it will tell you if any other version was available, then you can use absolute path to find about its version, like:

```
/usr/local/bin/qmake -v
```

Comment: yeah i can see it now in:           `QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.2 in /opt/qt54/lib`  but he is taken into consideration the previous one:        `Project MESSAGE: Qt version 5.2.1
                                                                                  Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quickwidgets`

Comment: How to make it consider QT5.4.2 version. Thanks

Comment: what was the output of `whereis qmake` ?

Comment: here it is the output : `qmake: /usr/bin/qmake /usr/bin/X11/qmake /opt/qt54/bin/qmake` Qt5.4.2 is in `/opt/qt54/bin/qmake` . kindly tell me how to make it as a default

Comment: So it's installed in `/opt` my suggestion is to create an alias: `alias qmake="/opt/qt54/bin/qmake"` you can add this line at the end of `~/.bashrc` so it will be available in all your terminals.

Comment: I did it but still when i do `qmake -v` the Qt5.2.1 appears.  Any other suggestions please

Comment: what is the output of `/opt/qt54/bin/qmake -v` ?

Comment: here it is the output `Using Qt version 5.4.2 in /opt/qt54/lib` but when i compile to install ardupilot it uses Qt5.2.1 how can i change it to Qt5.4.2

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you can do something like this (Not a good Idea): `sudo mv /usr/bin/qmake /usr/bin/qmake-bk` then `sudo ln -s /opt/qt54/bin/qmake /usr/bin/qmake`

Comment: Well guys, I could make Qt5.4.2 as a default by just editing `default.conf` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser` .I just added the path of Qt5.4.2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/opt/qt54/bin` for a file called *qt54-env.sh*. If the file is not there open Files file browser at `/opt/qt54/` and search for *qt54-env.sh* from there. Source `/opt/qt54/lib/qt54-env.sh` to set the correct environment.

```
cd  
source /opt/qt54/lib/qt54-env.sh
```

Comment: i tried to run the command you gave but it shows this error:                                                update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for qmake

Comment: I think it is installed here `Qt version 5.4.2 in /opt/qt54/lib` but how to make it as a default